# How to change width of Joomla module

Tags: joomla2.5

I dont understand how to change width of module.

I find use Firebug that this not in css. Look :

```
element.style {
width: 50%;
min-height: 439px;
}
```

I need to change this width. I use option to search files with this keywords. But nothing. 
I understand that this add by using Java Script or something like this.

My Joomla version 2.5.3

Answer (score 1):

This **width** is created dynamically with javascript in module files.

You have to search `/modules/*module_name/` to find the code that creating it (or if you are using a template override `/templates/*your_template/html/*module_name/`).

You could also add a css rule to override it like:

```
.class_name {
width: 100% !important;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for answer. I know about this variant, and i use it. It's  work. But this is not a best decision. I must be a JavaScript jedi to do some changes in js code ?

Comment: Which of these two. Css option is not a good decision that's right but you have to find where the code is created, there is not another option.